# Visual C++ (VS2010) Form Design Considerations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, interface, c++-cli

I'm working on building a form for use in an experimental study and am trying to create a consistent interface.

So far, I have a Form1 which allows users to select different instances of Form2.

What I would like is to be able to change properties of Form1 elements (such as enabled status and checkbox checkstates) upon closing Form2.

How might I go about this? I've tried declaring global variables in my base .cpp file, but those don't seem to be visible to the forms and I'm not certain if it will update the status of the items after the form has already loaded.

Comment: Is this [c++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)?  Or is it [c++/cli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)?  Despite the similar names, they are two different languages.

Comment: Not certain quite how to answer that, but it's the Windows Form option underneath Visual Studio 2010, utilizing CLR:pure. Beyond that, I would need more detail to be able to answer properly.

Comment: That's c++/cli then.  Be careful with Microsoft sources, they will tend to blur the line, referring to c++/cli as c++.  If you were wanting to learn actual c++, you should be informed that you're on the wrong path.

Comment: I'm interested in the solution itself, not so much the methods. This is for an engineering research project, so I'm not particularly worried about the finer points.

Comment: Just as a clarification: I think the above came off more terse than intended. I appreciate the qualification and will definitely keep that in mind; I just get bogged down in all of the documentation seeing as my goal is primarily functional rather than skill-building.